# What is the best way to optimize this React component to make it reusable?

Tags: reactjs, components, reusability, react-component

I'm a beginner in React and I've seen for the moment only the basics. I have a task at work which consists in making the component of the Terms Of Services whis is in OptInPage.jsx reusable. I tried several things without really understanding what I was doing, I looked at the documentation but the examples seems to be more basic than my problem. 
I was thinking of extracting the page   and creating a new TermsOfServices component to integrate between the jsx tags  . 
The problem here is that on the one hand, there should be a "read only" property to prevent the user from modifying the content, and on the other hand, I don't really understand how to pass props from my OptinPage component to my new TermsOfServices component.
Sorry in advance if my problem may seem stupid or something like that, I'm really stuck with that. Thank you in advance for your help.

OptinPage.jsx

```
import API from 'api';
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { FormattedMessage, intlShape } from 'react-intl';
import {
  Block,
  BlockTitle,
  Col,
  Fab,
  Icon,
  Link,
  NavRight,
  Navbar,
  Page,
  Popup,
  Preloader,
} from 'framework7-react';
import { connect } from 'react-refetch';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
import './OptInPage.scss';

class OptInPage extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    agreeTosFunc: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    agreeTos: PropTypes.object,
    logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSucceeded: PropTypes.func,
    opened: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    tos: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  static contextTypes = {
    apiURL: PropTypes.string,
    intl: intlShape,
    loginToken: PropTypes.string,
    logout: PropTypes.func,
    userId: PropTypes.string,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    agreeTos: {},
    onSucceeded: () => {},
  };

  state = {
    currentTos: -1,
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {
      agreeTos,
      onSucceeded,
      opened,
      tos,
    } = this.props;
    const { currentTos } = this.state;

    /* Reset currentTos on opened */
    if (!prevProps.opened && opened) {
      this.setState({ currentTos: -1 });
    }

    /* Prepare for first tos after receiving all of them */
    if (
      prevProps.tos.pending &&
      tos.fulfilled &&
      tos.value.length &&
      currentTos < 0
    ) {
      this.setState({ currentTos: 0 });
    }

    /* When sending ToS agreement is done */
    if (
      prevProps.agreeTos.pending &&
      agreeTos.fulfilled
    ) {
      onSucceeded();
    }
  }

  handleNext = () => {
    const { agreeTosFunc, tos } = this.props;
    const { currentTos: currentTosId } = this.state;
    const termsOfServices = tos.value;
    const done = currentTosId + 1 === termsOfServices.length;
    this.setState({ currentTos: currentTosId + 1 });
    if (done) {
      agreeTosFunc(termsOfServices.map((v) => v._id));
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { logout, opened, tos } = this.props;
    const { intl } = this.context;
    const { formatMessage } = intl;
    const { currentTos: currentTosId } = this.state;
    const termsOfServices = tos.value;
    const currentTermsOfServices = termsOfServices && termsOfServices[currentTosId];
    const loaded = termsOfServices && !tos.pending && tos.fulfilled;
    const htmlTransformCallback = (node) => {
      if (node.type === 'tag' && node.name === 'a') {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        node.attribs.class = 'external';
      }
      return undefined;
    };

    return (
      <Popup opened={opened} className="demo-popup-swipe" tabletFullscreen>
        <Page id="optin_page">
          <Navbar title={formatMessage({ id: 'press_yui_tos_title' })}>
            <NavRight>
              <Link onClick={() => logout()}>
                <FormattedMessage id="press_yui_comments_popup_edit_close" />
              </Link>
            </NavRight>
          </Navbar>
          { (!loaded || !currentTermsOfServices) && (
            <div id="optin_page_content" className="text-align-center">
              <Block className="row align-items-stretch text-align-center">
                <Col><Preloader size={50} /></Col>
              </Block>
            </div>
          )}
          { loaded && currentTermsOfServices && (
            <div id="optin_page_content" className="text-align-center">
              <h1>
                <FormattedMessage id="press_yui_tos_subtitle" values={{ from: currentTosId + 1, to: termsOfServices.length }} />
              </h1>
              <BlockTitle>
                {ReactHtmlParser(
                  currentTermsOfServices.title,
                  { transform: htmlTransformCallback },
                )}
              </BlockTitle>
              <Block strong inset>
                <div className="tos_content">
                  {ReactHtmlParser(
                    currentTermsOfServices.html,
                    { transform: htmlTransformCallback },
                  )}
                </div>
              </Block>
              <Fab position="right-bottom" slot="fixed" color="pink" onClick={() => this.handleNext()}>
                {currentTosId + 1 === termsOfServices.length &&
                  <Icon ios="f7:check" aurora="f7:check" md="material:check" />}
                {currentTosId !== termsOfServices.length &&
                  <Icon ios="f7:chevron_right" aurora="f7:chevron_right" md="material:chevron_right" />}
              </Fab>
              {currentTosId > 0 && (
              <Fab position="left-bottom" slot="fixed" color="pink" onClick={() => this.setState({ currentTos: currentTosId - 1 })}>
                <Icon ios="f7:chevron_left" aurora="f7:chevron_left" md="material:chevron_left" />
              </Fab>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </Page>
      </Popup>
    );
  }
}

export default connect.defaults(new API())((props, context) => {
  const { apiURL, userId } = context;
  return {
    tos: {
      url: new URL(`${apiURL}/tos?outdated=false&required=true`),
    },
    agreeTosFunc: (tos) => ({
      agreeTos: {
        body: JSON.stringify({ optIn: tos }),
        context,
        force: true,
        method: 'PUT',
        url: new URL(`${apiURL}/users/${userId}/optin`),
      },
    }),
  };
})(OptInPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you need smth like this.
First of all, you need to create a new file with you component and put the next code there

```
// don't forget to clean the unused imports
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { FormattedMessage, intlShape } from 'react-intl';
import {Block, BlockTitle, Col, Fab, Icon, Link, NavRight, Navbar, Page, Popup, Preloader } from 'framework7-react';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
export default class YourCLassName extends PureComponent<Props, State> {
    static propTypes = {
        currentTosId: PropTypes.object, // write correct type here
        termsOfServices: PropTypes.object, // write correct type here
        currentTermsOfServices: PropTypes.string, // write correct type here
        handleNext: PropTypes.func, // write correct type here
        handlePrev: PropTypes.func, // write correct type here
    };

    function htmlTransformCallback (node) => {
      if (node.type === 'tag' && node.name === 'a') {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        node.attribs.class = 'external';
      }
      return undefined;
    };


  render() {
    const { currentTosId, termsOfServices, currentTermsOfServices } = this.props;

    return (
        <div id="optin_page_content" className="text-align-center">
          <h1>
            <FormattedMessage id="press_yui_tos_subtitle" values={{ from: currentTosId + 1, to: termsOfServices.length }} />
          </h1>
          <BlockTitle>
            {ReactHtmlParser(
              currentTermsOfServices.title,
              { transform: htmlTransformCallback },
            )}
          </BlockTitle>
          <Block strong inset>
            <div className="tos_content">
              {ReactHtmlParser(
                currentTermsOfServices.html,
                { transform: htmlTransformCallback },
              )}
            </div>
          </Block>
          <Fab position="right-bottom" slot="fixed" color="pink" onClick={() => this.props.handleNext()}>
            {currentTosId + 1 === termsOfServices.length &&
              <Icon ios="f7:check" aurora="f7:check" md="material:check" />}
            {currentTosId !== termsOfServices.length &&
              <Icon ios="f7:chevron_right" aurora="f7:chevron_right" md="material:chevron_right" />}
          </Fab>
          {currentTosId > 0 && (
          <Fab position="left-bottom" slot="fixed" color="pink" onClick={() => this.props.handlePrev())}>
            <Icon ios="f7:chevron_left" aurora="f7:chevron_left" md="material:chevron_left" />
          </Fab>
          )}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

And in the OptinPage.jsx you need to replace all this code that concerns your newComponent with

```
<YourComponentName currentTosId={this.state.currentTosId} termsOfServices={termsOfServices} currentTermsOfServices={currentTermsOfServices} handleNext={this.handleNext} handlePrev={this.handlePrev} />
```

So the main point is to cut off the code, that you think can be performed by one component, and send it through props
You can also save necessary state in component itself, not in a parent component, if no other component needs these props

Comment: I changed a few things compared to my code but it works very well, thank you for your explanations and the example

Comment: I have a trouble with my currentTosId. I have an error in my console which is : 

index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `currentTosId` is marked as required in `TermsOfServices`, but its value is `undefined`.

This has the consequence of showing me a NAN in my OptinPage when it displays the state. Do you have any idea where this may come from?

Comment: if you are sending currentTosId through props (like <Component currentTosId={someValue} />) - this may mean that you are sending the wrong variable (maybe, it doesn't exist or you misspelled it).
But if it is possible, that the variable can be undefined, you need just fix your props and not render it, if it's not defined (like (typeof currentTosId !== 'undefined' && (<span>{currentTosId}</span>))